# Read files in u-boot

Tags: linux, file, u-boot

How can I read the file which is located on boot partition in u-boot? I can use fatload to read this file to ram but how then I can read it? I can write some additional command by u-boot makro U_BOOT_CMD but don't know how to use emmc and file there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use a two steps approach, this would avoid using emmc specific code in your u-boot custom command:

1. loading the file into memory,
2. use a custom u-boot command for reading it from memory.

For example:

```
fatload mmc 0 0x3000000 file.bin
m4xell 0x3000000
```

Your custom `m4xell` u-boot command would then be able to access the file content at `0x3000000`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I used memory compare. It works great. I load the files to the memory and then compare this memory.

Comment: Would consider accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark ? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @Frant Is there any restriction for the address? How did you choose 0x3000000? How do you know it is free and is there a maximum to put in?

Comment: @Mehmet Fide: `0x3000000` is an arbitrary value chosen for the purpose of the answer. In the case of a real-life example, you would have to look at the output of the u-boot `printenv` or the linux `fw_printenv` commands on your target system in order to determine which address could be used. For example, on my i.MX7D board, I have:  `addr_dtb=8121aa00`  `addr_initramfs=80f04800`
`addr_kernel=80800000` I could therefore use for example `0x80f04800` for the m4xell command. You can look at the u-boot source code for more information on suitable addresses for your system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *mm* command to display the memory content.

You can run the the UEFI shell using the *bootefi* command. Inside the UEFI shell the *edit* command can display files. The UEFI shell is delivered with Tianocore EDK II.

Comment: I used cmp to compare two memory block where I loaded the files content. I needed this to decide if some file contain some text. I created source file with this text and second one which is dynamically change, then i load to memory both and compare by cmp.